# Cross thread from a Class module

Tags: vb.net

I have a class module that uses a named pipe as a listener. It's thread is started from the UI. When it receives data I want to return the data to the UI for processing.

I've tried several examples of Invoke but none of them work. The last error message was that the UI Window's handle needed to be assigned.

The following is in the `frmUDPTest`:

```
Delegate Sub ReturnDelegate(ByVal text As String)
Public doReturn As ReturnDelegate

Public Sub DisplayReturn(ByVal ServerResponse As String)
    VBL_RETURN.Text = "Server Return: " & ServerResponse
End Sub
```

The following is the NamedPipe receiver in a Class named `ClientPipe`:

```
Public Shared Sub Receive()
    'This is on a separate thread
    'This is the receiver for the Local UDPServer's return to 
    'the requesting client
    'The pipe's name is passed to the Local UDPserver in the request
    'This routine is on a seperate thread and is started prior to any 
    'communications to the local UDPserver.

    Dim RequestBytes(64) As Byte
    Dim RequestByteCount As Integer = 0
    Dim Response As String
    Try
        frmUDPTEST.doReturn = New frmUDPTEST.ReturnDelegate(AddressOf frmUDPTEST.DisplayReturn)
        ClientReceive = New NamedPipeServerStream(ClientPipeName, PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous)
        While True
            ClientReceive.WaitForConnection()
            RequestByteCount = ClientReceive.Read(RequestBytes, 0, ByteSize)
            If RequestByteCount > 0 Then
                Response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RequestBytes)  'Convert bytes back to string

                '>>>>> Problem occurs here <<<<<
                frmUDPTEST.Invoke(frmUDPTEST.doReturn, New Object() {Response})

            End If
            ClientReceive.Disconnect()
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Need the returned data from the named pipe processed by UI routines to be passed on to the client that made the request.

Comment: What is the "Problem occurs here"? What problem?

Comment: Enigmativity I get an error that says the Windows handle has not been created.. I started the Receivers thread from the window frmUDPTest in a button press event.

Comment: Where in your code does `frmUDPTEST` get instantiated and shown?

Comment: *"I have a class module"*. No you don't. A class is a class and a module is a module. Those terms have specific meanings in VB.NET. If your code file starts with `Public Class` then you have a class and if it starts with `Public Module` then you have a module.

Comment: It is a class called Clientpipe that holds a client named pipe, receiver, and server pipe, sender. The receiver's thread is started in frmUDPtest prior to using the server pipe to send a request to a UDP protocalled LAN server program. The server gets a return value and returns it to the receiver. All that works fine. What I am unable to solve is getting the returned value back to the frmUDPTest for processing.